# Expected "assets" to be a list, but got null (Null)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to add image through assets in pubsec.yaml but it keep giving me the error below:

pubsec.yaml code:

```
name: grid_project
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/bus.png
    - assets/circle.png
    - assets/info.png
    - assets/phone.png
    - assets/play.png
    - assets/square.png

  uses-material-design: true
```

The problem appears on `assets` word below `flutter`, the error says "*The value of the 'asset' field is expected to be a list of relative file paths.
Try converting the value to be a list of relative file paths.dart(asset_field_not_list)*"

Comment: Hmm, looks good to me. Are you sure the error comes from the pubspec.yaml file and not the code somewhere else? Also, what's your file structure in the project (where do you keep your assets)?

Comment: I am sure that the error come from the pubsec.yaml file, in the output tab it gives me this "Error detected in pubspec.". The images are in a folder called assets in the project root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there You should put the spacing between '-' and the assets/images

Answer (score 0):

With multiple files like this, make a file within your assets folder.
Example:  `assets/images` then place all the files within that images folder.

In your pubspec:

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
```

then you'll be able to access the whole folder without adding all of the files individually.

Comment: You forgot to add the space between the dash and assets in the path, anyway it didn't work for me either.

Comment: Is your asset file in the root of the project?

Comment: Yes it's in the root

Comment: Can you please tell me where are you using these assets in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have such problem in my pubspec.yaml and only difference between your code and mine is spacing before - assets/bus.png and uses-material-design: true is above assets.

[Here's the spinnet from pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cAMI.png)
If this spacing and position fix didn't work check whether you're providing correct image paths.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Paste this in `Pubspec.yaml`

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Make sure that you have assets folder in the root directory and having the "images" folder in it which contains your project images